# Search within table?

Tags: search, table

I have a nice plugin that is called Select WP-Table Reloaded and that works well, except the contents don't show up in a useful manner.

The page the table is embedded shows up in a search, but not the specific term.
Is there any way to remedy this?
This is the page the table is embedded in:  http://henschelhausbooks.com/authorsbooks/

If you were to search for an author, like "Baake", only the page with the short blurb would show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggested here by [JLeuse](http://wpcandy.com/broadcasts/the-sweet-plugin/day-4#comment-122821). It seems the contents within WP Table Reloaded is indeed separated from the post, which means the default Wordpress search function won't be able to fetch it...

Comment: yeah, I figured.  Was just hoping someone had a slick plugin that could search within site content AND the WP Table. On the whole, I like WP Tables  too much to switch to another plugin.